# mySQL sorts underscore last

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sorting

I have a column in my table that stores a string (it is a text column):

varchar(16)
latin1_swedish_ci

The problem is, when I say "ORDER BY name ASC" it returns words starting with an underscore at the end. This is an example it returned:

```
-a
-mmddd2
-z
-z3
aaa
b
c
t
_a
___-
```

I bet I can use php to sort, but is there an easy way to make mySQL put the underscores after the dashes? I am doing this so it will match the output of the javascript sort function.

I'm trying to get:

```
-a
-mmddd2
-z
-z3
_a
___-
aaa
b
c
t
```

Answer (score 5):

[Collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-applications.html) define the sort order, if none of the available collations use the sort order you need you can define your own, as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-collation-simple-8bit.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying this is an elegant solution, but you could try doing something like this:

```
select name
from customers
order by replace(name, '_', '-+') asc;
```

Just replace the + with whatever will put the prefixed underscore values after the dash.

Comment: Note that an ORDER BY clause that uses a computation will ruin the benefit from indexes on its fields.